# Perché si usa il congiuntivo imperfetto in una proposizione subordinata introdotta da "prima che"?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, tenses

> Prima che partissimo ci ha dato documenti falsi.

Perché il congiuntivo imperfetto è stato usato in questa frase? 
Secondo me, il congiuntivo passato sarebbe dovuto essere usato qui.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105058/discussion-on-question-by-damian-perche-si-usa-il-congiuntivo-imperfetto-in-ques).

Comment: Sulla [*Nueva gramática de la lengua española*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGUZAkDawmpPpiHm) dell'Accademia della lingua
ho trovato una regola che indica che, in una frase con "prima che" (in spagnolo "antes de que"), se il verbo della proposizione principale è al passato, quello della subordinata deve essere al congiuntivo imperfetto oppure al congiuntivo trapassato. Invece, se il verbo della proposizione principale è al presente o futuro, allora il verbo della subordinata deve essere al congiuntivo presente o passato. Immagino che la stessa regola sia valida per l'italiano.